# How to configure Pulseaudio to make laptop speakers and headphones work simultaneously?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I have a laptop with Ubuntu Eoan. Single soundcard, single headphone jack.

I want to use both laptop speakers and headphones at the same time (no particular reason why, just because) but as soon as I plug in the headphones, the speakers become unavailable.

I tried enabling simultaneous output, removing -switch-on-connect and -switch-on-port-available modules and making a virtual sink, but nothing works. Google search returns only the reverse problem, of people **not** wanting speakers and headphones to play at the same time.

Anyone has any solutions?

Output of `amixer -c0`:

```
 Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
 Playback channels: Mono
 Limits: Playback 0 - 87
 Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
 Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
 Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: Playback 0 - 87
 Mono:
 Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
 Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
 Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
 Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: Playback 0 - 87
 Mono:
 Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
 Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
 Capabilities: pvolume
 Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: Playback 0 - 255
 Mono:
 Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
 Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
 Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
 Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: Playback 0 - 31
 Mono:
 Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
 Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
 Capabilities: volume
 Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: 0 - 3
 Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
 Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
 Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
 Playback channels: Mono
 Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
 Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
 Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: Capture 0 - 63
 Front Left: Capture 47 [75%] [18.00dB] [on]
 Front Right: Capture 47 [75%] [18.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
 Capabilities: enum
 Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
 Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic',0
 Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
 Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: Playback 0 - 31
 Mono:
 Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
 Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
 Capabilities: volume
 Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
 Limits: 0 - 3
 Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
 Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
 Capabilities: enum
 Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
 Item0: 'Disabled'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speakers are muted when headphones are plugged in by this setting in ALSA

```
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
 Capabilities: enum
 Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
 Item0: 'Enabled'
```

change this to **Disabled**

```
amixer -c0 sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' Disabled
```

and save ALSA settings so that ALSA keeps settings when system is restored

```
sudo alsactl store
```

Answer (score 0):

While your headphones are connected, run `alsamixer` in a terminal, press `F6` to choose your Sound Card and:

1. Disable `Auto-Mute Mode`: Move to `Auto-Mute Mode`, then DOWN to disable. (nik gnomic's answer also applies here)
2. Unmute `Speaker` and increase its volume to 100%: Move to `Speaker`, press `M` to unmute, then UP or PgUP to increase the volume.

[image: alsamixer]

These were the steps that worked for me.